# System.Diagnostics.Tracing in .net core app running on linux

Tags: .net, .net-core, system.diagnostics

Using System.Diagnostics.Tracing on windows  and doing e.g.

```
this.WriteEvent(1, message);
```

results in message written to windows event logs and can be viewed using eventviewer or picked up by a centralized logging framework.

My question is on Linux, there is no such thing as windows events, so where do these messages go?
And what is the best practice for consuming/viewing these messages?
I looked in /var/log and dont see anything.

From some searching, I have came across LTTng, but dont quite get it.